# Find all instances where a pandas dataframe containing a column of int's matches a dataframe with a column of a list of ints

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes.  One (a) has a column of integers and one (b) has a column of a list of integers (array or list)

I'm trying to find a way to find all occurrences of b where b contains a.

I hoped something like this would work

```
df3 = a[a['cell'].isin(b['cells'])]
```

But I get an empty dataframe.

Comment: you want to compare these two df's row by row if integer in a is in the list of b? can you add some sample of your data and your desired output?

Comment: Can you share a sample dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using columns 'a' and 'b' in the same dataframe.
Here is the filter that worked for me on an example dataframe I made.

```
data=pd.DataFrame([[1, [1, 2, 3]], [5, [11, 12, 13]], [6, [7, 6, 10]]], columns=['a', 'b'])
mask=(pd.Series(data.index)).apply(lambda x:(data.loc[x, ['a']]).isin(data.loc[x, ['b']].values[0]))
```

data:

[image]

data.loc[mask['a'].values]:

[image]